# Laravel access route parameter in route web.php file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6

The parameter is posted to `some_name` like this:
`{{ route('some_name', $id = '1'}}`
How can I access it in the if condition?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/'], function()
{
    if ( condition )
    {
        Route::get('/route/{id}', 'ControllerA@methodA')->name('some_name');
    } else{
        Route::get('/route{id}', 'ControllerB@methodB')->name('some_name');;
    }
});
```

How can I use the `{id}` parameter in the `if (condition)`?
I tried

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/'], function($id)
    {
        if ( $id == 1)
```

And it's not working.

Comment: You'd have to use `"prefix" => "{id}` for `$id` to be available in `function($id)`. Honestly not sure what you're trying to handle here. You can use `{id?}` for optional params, with `function($id = null)`, then handle case if `$id` is `null` or not, so maybe try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing you can do is a Middleware, for example:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->id == 'some_value') {
        redirect action('ControllerA@methodA');
    }
    else {
      redirect action('ControllerB@methodB');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: What do you think is better: your solution or doing only one route and checking the condition in the controller and returning the appropiate view? Both work for me I would like to know which one is better.

Comment: I think that depends of how different is the logic, if you are performing an A/B testing, I think is better your solution. So if there is no major changes in the logic to create a new controller, just show the corresponding view according the condition @Victordb

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs, personally i've never done an `if` inside my routes folder, besides that, it's really dangerous to practice stuff like that, make everything happen in the views, if you are messing up with user logged in or not, do `auth::check()` or something like that, but never play with the routes `web.php` to ensure security in your app, everything else is made on the controllers and views.

Comment: I ended up doing only one route, check the condition inside the controller and return the appropriate view. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good practice to validate the id in the route file to redirect to different controllers, and heres why:

You'll send a request to that endpoint and send an ID.

1. Is that ID valid? How do you know?
2. Is the ID an integer or a string?
3. Does ID exists in the request?

and with these 3 questions, you'll end up having validations + redirect to different methods and if it's an ID of interest to a database query, you'll have database code in there aswell.

The normal procedure I like to think is when it hits the route, it should hit Authorization and Authentication (middleware as Bak87 said). In there, you can validate if he's authenticated, if he's a certain user, whatever you'd like.

Afterwards this initial validation, you can redirect it to a certain method in a certain controller depending on your needs, however, I wouldn't advise as a class should have a single purpose according to some standards (but in the end, you can build the application how you want it).

I believe a route or a group of routes should have an middleware (for whatever primary validation you require of the person making the request), and each route should point to a single method in a controller. Once it reaches the controller, instead of having (Request $request) as the parameters for the method, you can have your own custom FormRequest, where you can validate the ID if you'd like.

If FormRequest isn't of interest, you can use Eloquent (if the ID you're looking for is related to it) `FindOrFail` to validate if it exists (if it doesn't, returns a 404 error not found, if you have a 404.blade.php file). This way, by the time it reaches the controller's method, it has been validated by sections, where routes are then protected by the main Authorization and Authentication, FormRequest to do the input's validation and you can specifically return whatever you'd like from the controller's method.

Obviously we don't know what is the view your returning but if slighty differs from each other, consider refactoring it in order to return only 1 view, composed of other blades